# assertListEqual negation (opposite)

Tags: python, python-unittest

There are functions: `assertSequenceEqual`, `assertListEqual` and `assertTupleEqual` in unittest module.

But how can I achive the opposite behavior? How can I assert that lists are unequal?

Comment: `assertNotEqual(a,b)`? Is that what you wanted? FYI, there are lots of other unittest methods mentioned here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html. As far as the doc. is concerned there is no `notEqual` equivalent for unittest module in Python. There is another unit testing module called PyUnit - but I am not sure if they have this `assertNotListEqual(..)` type of methods either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those functions are actually used by [`TestCase.assertEqual()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual), when both values are the same type and a type-specific method is present.

The inverse is simply to use [`TestCase.assertNotEqual()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertNotEqual).

There are no nice 'formatting' options in that case, but if the test fails, that'd means that both lists were equal, so there is no *point* in showing how they match exactly!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `assertNotEqual` to test that two sequences are unequal. The main feature of sequence related assertions is their ability to compute the difference between subjects upon failure.